# Please help identify this vintage SKIP bike. Thanks

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

I have a friend who has this bike and he is having trouble finding any information on this bicycle.

I'm not trying to sell anything I’m more interested in the history of this machine.

[image]

Comment: Looked at the images.  It's an interesting bike.  A bit but not terribly unusual, but in good condition for its age.  Looks like a hub brake on the rear.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I haven’t been able to find any information on this bike besides what you have just told me. The bike just says SKIP and has a logo of a triangle. Thanks again

Comment: @DanielRHicks, they look more like a cable actuated band brake to me. Or do you think it has a third brake?

Comment: Arthur, would you have a closer up of the front brake? It looks unusual, but that might be only artifacts from the present image. The bike looks a little like a Mamachari. Weekend you check the tyre size on the sidewall? Is it 700c etrto 622?

Comment: @gschenk - Yeah, a brake attached to the hub.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it an 80s step-through frame, intended for a woman (denoted by the skirt guard on the rear wheel)

Three black cables show there are two brakes, and probably a 3 speed internal gear hub in the rear wheel.

Observation - there's a lot of seatpost and an awful lot of stem out of the bike - guessing this is a small frame and the current rider is quite tall.   Do check that the "minimum insertion" lines are not visible - if so then the stem/seatpost have to go down a bit.

I'd also guess that the bike had a stout front basket at some point.  That  upright stay on the front wheel is a lot more beefy than the other stay holding the rear of the front guard.  My suspicion is the basket clipped into the headlight holder and bolted to the small horizontal area over the front mudguard.

Can't put anything against the *35 25* stickers on the front fork - possibly some local registration scheme, or maybe an allocated bike park slot somewhere.

The tyres appear to have that reflective side strip, so they seem relatively recent, certainly not original rubber which would be tan on the side.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I haven’t been able to find any information on this bike besides what you have just told me. The bike just says SKIP and has a logo of a triangle. Thanks